# How to change image of image button from gallery in Android?

Tags: android, imagebutton

How to change image button image at runtime ?

```
ibtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ibtn.setBackground      
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first pick an image from gallery and then set that image to your button background.

Use this function to pick image from gallery

```
public void pickImageFromGallery() {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_PHOTO_FOR_AVATAR);
}
```

And receive your image in OnActivityResult

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent      data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        final Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            //Get image
            Bitmap bitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
            ibtn.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```